# Сортировка в Perl

Tags: perl

Здравствуйте!
Разбираюсь с Perl, помогите с сортировкой...

Следующий код:

```
open(FILE,"<file");
@text = <FILE>;
chomp(@text);
close(FILE);
```

Каждая строчка в файле представляет из себя данные, записанные через разделитель `"|"`, т.е.

> ```
> фио|адрес|телефон|
> фио|адрес|телефон|
> ```

Нужно отсортировать по фио, причем могут быть как русские так и английские символы.
Спасибо!

Comment: chomp(@text); разве будет работать ?

Comment: perldoc -f chomp

...
CHOMP( LIST )

Answer (score 3):

```
sort {
    [split /\|/, $a]->[0] cmp [split /\|/, $b]->[0]
} @text;
```

Про русский покурить про locale и unicode.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open FILE,'file.txt';
chomp(my @info=<FILE>);
print sort @info;
```

Такой вариант не есть хорошо ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Handle>
chomp;
```

Так тоже будет работать.